# Oracle DB links and retrieving stale data

Tags: oracle

I have 2 databases, DBa and DBb. I have 2 records sets, RecordsA and RecordsB. The concept is that in our app you can add records from A to B. I am having an issue where I go to add a record from A to B and try to query the records again. The particular property on the added record is stale/incorrect.

RecordsA lives on DBa and RecordsB lives on DBb. I make my stored proc call to add the record to the B side and modify a column's value on DBa which makes the insert/update using a dblink on DBb. Problem is, when I do a insert/update followed by an immidiate get call on DBa (calling DBb) that modified property is incorrect, it's null as if the insert never went through. However, if I put a breakpoint before the pull call and wait about 1 second the correct data is returned. Making me wonder if there is some latency issues with dblinks.

This seems like an async issue but we verified no async calls are being made and everything is running on the same thread. Would this type of behavior be likely with a db link? As in, inserting/updating a record on a remote server and retrieving it right away causing some latency where the record wasn't quite updated at the time of the re-pull?

Comment: which versions of Oracle, are the DB in the same server room, same country, same continent?  Is the connection fast?   Just a few more details please.....

Comment: where is the stored proc located?  where are the commits happening?

Comment: What version(s) of Oracle and are either system running RAC?  In older versions of Oracle, you could configure RAC so that there was the potential for a delay between a change being committed on one node and when it became visible to queries on the other node.  That would be unlikely on recent versions of Oracle unless you went really out of your way.

Comment: Our version is 11g. The servers are located in the same building. Not sure about exact details there.